# Broken Link Checker Keeps Sending Request to My Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting, ping, ddos

I have a web app, running on an Amazon EC2 instance with and application load balancer. I was checking my broken links with https://www.brokenlinkcheck.com/ tool but I forgot to press the stop button and closed the window. Now, it has been continuously sending me requests. I would like to somehow stop it or block the IP. I have tried with AWS VNC console but its not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The https://www.brokenlinkcheck.com/ service appears to have limits (3000 pages) so it would probably stop after a while. It would be worthwhile confirming that this really is the source of the requests by looking at the requests being received.

The easiest way to stop these requests coming to your app would be:

- Determine the IP address of the incoming checks (hopefully they are only coming from one IP address, or a small number of them
- Add a **Network ACL (NACL) rule** to your VPC Subnet that denies incoming traffic on port 80 and 443 from that IP address

See: [Network ACLs - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-rules)

This will prevent traffic coming from that IP address from entering the VPC Subnet. The requests will never reach your application.